# SQL directly output timestamp

Tags: php, sql

I have a column in a table in SQL with type "Timestamp", which sais that it is actually recording the data/time with the number of how many seconds have passed since sometime.

I'm wondering how can I directly output that timestamp NUMBER. Since everytime I use "select", it always outputs a formated string like "xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx" which is really inconvenient for my PHP code outside. I need to do math on those numbers.

I know that I can convert the string back to the timestamp in PHP but I think it is sort of really stupid since SQL is formating it and PHP is converting it back.

Thanks!

### EDT1

To be more clear, rather than output something like "2015-03-13 3:50:00", can SQL directly output the timestamp in Unix Timestamp form e.g. 1426218604? I think it's actually what's recorded in the db binary file.

And for SQL engine, I'm not sure is it MySQLAdmin or InnoDB or something else.

Comment: Please explain what do u want to do ?..I am unable to understand this question

Comment: Please get into the habit of specifying what DB engine you are using. To illustrate why, In SQL server the timestamp datatype is like a rowversion and nothing to do with date/time.

Comment: Use Mysql `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_field);`

Comment: @BheemRaj Is there any "global" setting I can do, so that when I'm using "select * from table", I can directly get all timestamp in Unix Timestamp form? Since calling UNIX_TIMESTAMP each time i'm tring to get a timestamp in PHP is sort of even slower

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this around it:

```
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'now' ) );
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx' ) );
```

Formatting in various ways is here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php